# How to limit count of threads in many threadpools?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

Fixed threadpool can limit the count of executing thread.

`ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);`

If I have several threadpools, is there a way to limit the overall number of threads in threadpools?

```
ExecutorService poolA = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
ExecutorService poolB = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
ExecutorService poolC = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
ExecutorService poolD = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
...
```

I want to limit the total count of threads that execute in the same time.

For example, I have 4 threadPools. Each of their size is 8. Now I have many threads to run. But I want only 15 threads to run and the other thread to wait in the same time.

---

There is a public method that can called by many classes. The method costs a lot of time and resources. The parameter of this method is a path and files in the path will be parsed. I don't want the method to parse the files in the same time. Because it costs a lot of time and resources--, and the parsed result can be reused by other calls. But I also don't want only one parse process to run in the same time. If the resource of server is enough, the processes with different path can run in parallel. So I create a map. The key is path and the value is a thread pool. It can help me to control the process.

```
static Map<String, ExecutorService> map = new HashMap<>();

public void method(String path, Thread thread) {
    if (!map.containsKey(path)) {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadPool();
        map.put(path, pool);
    }
    map.get(path).submit(thread);
}
```

If there are two calls with one path, they will run one by one. I can set a judgement in thread for checking whether the parse result is generated. If there are two calls with different path, they will run in parallel to save time.

I don't know how to control the count of running threads in the same time. Because it may uses too more resources.

Comment: Use a single thread pool.

Comment: What would be the point of having "a lot" of thread pools? It might make sense for some, sophisticated application to have _a few_ pools—pools that run a different priorities, or pools for different classes of job—but how many is "a lot?" and how would the application benefit from having more than just a few?

Answer (score 1):

As it has been pointed out in the comments, you could achieve what you're asking by using only one `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

In fact, a `ThreadPoolExecutor` contains a pool of threads whose number is adjusted according to the `CorePoolSize` and `MaximumPoolSize` properties. The `PoolSize` property represents the current number of threads running or in idle within the `ThreadPoolExecutor`. While, the `CorePoolSize` and `MaximumPoolSize` represent the bounds for minimum and maximum thread creation.

- In fact, if a new task is submitted and fewer threads than `CorePoolSize` are running, a new thread is created, even if there are other threads in idle.
- If a new task is submitted and the number of threads is greater or equal than `CorePoolSize` but lower than `MaximumPoolSize` then a new thread is created **only** if the queue is full; otherwise the task is queued.
- Finally, if a new task is submitted when the `MaximumCoreSize` has been reached and the queue is full, then the task is rejected and handled by the default or provided `RejectedExecutionHandler` object which will invoke the `rejectedExecution` method to handle the rejection.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

In your case, to have at most 15 threads running at the same, you could just use the `newFixedThreadPool` method of the `Executors` class and pass 15 as the argument to have both `CorePoolSize` and `MaximumPoolSize` set to 15. Like so, you'll have at most 15 threads running at the same time within the same executor.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor pool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);
```